# Javascript merge arrays with same values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to merge arrays which includes same values to one array with javascript.

Example: Input array:

```
neighbours = [
 [0, 1],
 [1, 0, 2],
 [2, 1],
 [3, 4, 5],
 [4, 3, 6],
 [5, 3, 6],
 [6, 4, 5]
];
```

Output array:

```
pairs = [
 [0, 1, 2],
 [3, 4, 5, 6]
]
```

Is there a simple way to do this in javascript?

Comment: Can you explain what you actually want? With at least some detail please, some code to build on or some more explanation as to what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bruteforce solution.
hope its the one which you are looking for.

```
var neighbors = [
     [0, 1],
     [1, 0, 2],
     [2, 1],
     [3, 4, 5],
     [4, 3, 6],
     [5, 3, 6],
     [6, 4, 5]
];
var pairs=[];

pairs.push(neighbors[0]); 
var idx=0;
for(var i=1;i<neighbors.length;i++){
    var cur=neighbors [i];
var prev=neighbors [i-1];
var found=false;
for(var j=0;j<prev.length;j++){
    for(var k=0;k<cur.length;k++){
        if(prev[j]==cur[k]){
            found=true;
            if(!pairs[idx]) pairs[idx]=[];
            pairs[idx].push(cur);
            break;
        }
    }
    if(found) break;
    }
    if(!found) idx++;
}

for(var j=0;j<pairs.length;j++){
    pairs[j]=[...new Set(pairs[j].flat(Infinity))].sort((a,b)=>(a-b));

}
console.log(pairs);
```

let me know if you need explanation of it.

Comment: Won't it give wrong o/p when i/p is `var neighbors = [[0], [1], [2, 1, 0], [3, 4, 5], [4, 3, 6], [5, 3, 6], [6, 4, 5]];` ?

Answer (score 0):

Using object keys as set values try to repeatedly merge the sets into each other.

```js
const neighbours = [
 [0, 1],
 [1, 0, 2],
 [2, 1],
 [3, 4, 5],
 [4, 3, 6],
 [5, 3, 6],
 [6, 4, 5]
];


const neighbourSets = neighbours.map( list => list.reduce((a,v)=>(a[v]=undefined,a),{}) );

let pairs = [];
let next = neighbourSets.shift();
while(next) {
  const neighbourCount = Object.keys(next).length;
  for(const [index, pairCandidate] of Object.entries(pairs) ) {
    const merged = Object.assign({}, next, pairCandidate);
    // Check if there is overlap.
    if(Object.keys(merged).length < neighbourCount+Object.keys(pairCandidate).length) {
      delete pairs[index];
      next = merged;
    }
  }
  pairs.push(next);
  next = neighbourSets.shift();
}

pairs = pairs.filter(v=>v).map( o=>Object.keys(o).map(v=>Number(v)).sort() );
console.log(pairs);
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you!